# Pandoc and listings in YAML header?

Tags: markdown, pandoc, pdflatex

I have the following `test.md`:

````
---
listings: true # here it just seems to include usepackage, but still keeps code blocks in {verbatim}; only --listings on command line starts wrapping code block in lstlisting ?
title: "Some title here"
author: John Doe
date: \today
---

# Introduction

Here is some code output, obtained with the `devcon.exe` command line tool:

```
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_A295&SUBSYS_36E217AA&REV_F0\3&11583659&0&E0
    Name: Intel(R) 200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 - A295
    Driver is running.
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_5912&SUBSYS_36E217AA&REV_04\3&11583659&0&10
    Name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 630
    Driver is running.
ACPI\ACPI000C\2&DABA3FF&1
    Name: ACPI Processor Aggregator
    Driver is running.
```

So ...
````

So, if I build this as-is with pandoc, the code block is *still* wrapped in `{verbatim}` environment, even if `\usepackage{listings}` is included, due to the presence of `listings: true` in YAML header:

```
$ pandoc test.md -s -o test.tex && grep '\\begin\|list' test.tex
\usepackage{listings}
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
```

Only if I add the `--listings` switch to the command line, then I have the code block wrapped in `{lstlistings}` environment:

```
$ pandoc test.md --listings -s -o test.tex && grep '\\begin\|list' test.tex
\usepackage{listings}
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
```

My question is: is there any way I can just specify the use of `listings` in the YAML header *only* -- *without* having to use the `--listings` switch in the `pandoc` call on the command line?

EDIT: this is on pandoc 2.11.4

Answer (score 0):

There's an [open pandoc issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4627) about this.

You can use a wrapper script, or use pandoc's [--defaults option](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--defaults), which can be used as follows to specify command-line options from a file. If e.g. `input.md` contains:

```
---
listings: true
...

# my title

rest of my document
```

You can call pandoc as follows:

```
pandoc --defaults input.md input.md
```

Yes, currently you have to specify the file twice: once for the `--defaults` option to read out the YAML, and once as the markdown input file as usual.